# How to write down test class for If else condition

Tags: apex, unit-test

Scenario:
If First name or Email or both missing from existing contact then error message should be display.

................

Apex class controller

```
if(contact.Id !=null && contact.Email != null && contact.FirstName != null)
            {    
               System.debug('contact----------------'+contact);        
                PrepareUser();   

                insert user;
                if(user.Id!=null)
                {
                    //sendMail(user.Id);
                    if(!isSuperUser)
                            CommunityManageUsersController.NewUserAdded(user.Id);
                    return RedirectToUserMgntPage();
                }

                pageStatus = new PageStatus(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, LocalizationManager.GetLocalizedString('ManageCommunityUsers','AddingUserStatusMsg',''));
                System.debug('pageStatus----------------'+pageStatus);
                isProcessing=true;
            }

          else if(contact.FirstName == null && contact.Email == null ){
                params.put('{0}','FirstName ,Email');
               pageStatus=new PageStatus(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,LocalizationManager.GetLocalizedString('CommunityManageUsersStrings2','InvalidContactErrorMsg',params));
            }else if(contact.FirstName == null){
                params.put('{0}','FirstName');
               pageStatus=new PageStatus(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,LocalizationManager.GetLocalizedString('CommunityManageUsersStrings2','InvalidContactErrorMsg',params));
            }else if(contact.Email == null)
               params.put('{0}','Email');
               pageStatus=new PageStatus(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,LocalizationManager.GetLocalizedString('CommunityManageUsersStrings2','InvalidContactErrorMsg',params)); 

            }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {    
            pageStatus=new PageStatus(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'User already exist by that email');              
            //pageStatus = new PageStatus(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, ex.getMessage()+ ex.getStackTraceString());        
        }

        return null;
    }

..................
```

I write down like as below for all 3 condition but getting Error Message    System.AssertException: Assertion Failed.

```
@isTest
    static void AddUserByContactDataTest1()
    {
        Test.startTest();

        System.runAs(CommunityTestHelper.superAdmin)
        {   
            CommunityAddUserController controller=new CommunityAddUserController();
            controller.contact.FirstName=null;
            //controller.contact.LastName='AddUserByContactDataTest';
            controller.contact.Email=null;
            controller.contact.Description=CommunityTestHelper.testAccount.Id;

            List<SelectOption> options=controller.GetCustomerPortalProfiles();
            controller.selectedProfileId=options[0].getValue();

            PageReference pageRef=controller.CreatePortalUser();
            System.assert(pageRef!=null);
            System.assert(controller.user.Id!=null);
            System.assert(pageRef.getUrl().contains('CommunityAdminManageUsers'));
        }

        Test.stopTest();
    }

    @isTest
    static void AddUserByContactDataTest2()
    {
        Test.startTest();

        System.runAs(CommunityTestHelper.superAdmin)
        {   
            CommunityAddUserController controller=new CommunityAddUserController();
            controller.contact.FirstName='test';
            //controller.contact.LastName='AddUserByContactDataTest';
           // controller.contact.Email=null;
            controller.contact.Description=CommunityTestHelper.testAccount.Id;

            List<SelectOption> options=controller.GetCustomerPortalProfiles();
            controller.selectedProfileId=options[0].getValue();

            PageReference pageRef=controller.CreatePortalUser();
            System.assert(pageRef!=null);
            System.assert(controller.user.Id!=null);
            System.assert(pageRef.getUrl().contains('CommunityAdminManageUsers'));
        }

        Test.stopTest();
    }
    @isTest
    static void AddUserByContactDataTest3()
    {
        Test.startTest();

        System.runAs(CommunityTestHelper.superAdmin)
        {   
            CommunityAddUserController controller=new CommunityAddUserController();
           // controller.contact.FirstName=null;
            //controller.contact.LastName='AddUserByContactDataTest';
            controller.contact.Email='test@gmail.com';
            controller.contact.Description=CommunityTestHelper.testAccount.Id;

            List<SelectOption> options=controller.GetCustomerPortalProfiles();
            controller.selectedProfileId=options[0].getValue();

            PageReference pageRef=controller.CreatePortalUser();
            System.assert(pageRef!=null);
            System.assert(controller.user.Id==null);
            System.assert(pageRef.getUrl().contains('CommunityAdminManageUsers'));
        }

        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does anything populate `contact.Id` in your controller? Your tests assign values to `contact.Email` and `contact.FirstName`, but unless a Contact is inserted somewhere there will not be a valid Contact ID to use and the controller `if` will never be entered.

Answer (score 3):

It is very simple, you need to create two test method in your test class. 
In first method add conditions so that your if condition will be satisfied.
In second method add conditions so that if condition will not be satisfied and else part will be executed. So you will have code coverage for if part as well as else part.

Comment: @ Ankush ,Plz give me example .

Comment: Stop and think about it. Write a test method where its designed to pass and assert the conditions for passing at the end. Then write another test method using inputs where it's designed to fail and assert the conditions afterward. Try it and post your results. That's how you learn. If you have problems, tell us where and people are always happy to help those who show effort. There are examples of branch testing on blogs all over. Use http://findsf.info/ to locate them if you must.